# Spring mvc ,debug application

Tags: debugging, spring-mvc

when i code a sample of Spring mvc and ant build it ,i input the site at the web broswer.But it just say could not find the page.How can i debug the application?i just want to know the log and what exception is.thanks.

Comment: Turn up your logging level in logging.properties to ALL, or turn it upn in log4j or whatever logging framework Spring is using. You'll then see what the framework is doing. Aside from that, if you want more help, you're going to have to put a lot more effort into your question. Take a look around the site at the +1 and +2 voted questions to get an idea of what is expected. What you'll see are lots of details and working code posted by question-askers. Welcome to StackOverflow. Good luck!

Comment: Agree with jmort that you need more detail. One little bit to point you in the right direction... is it safe to assume you're using some flavor of Eclipse? Most Spring users are- most notably STS (SpringSource Tool Suite). If so, have a look at Window -> Show View -> Console. If something is seriously wrong on your server (assuming you started it through Eclipse) then it should be evident there. If not, then as jmort suggested, you need to turn your logging levels down to debug or info. In a modern Spring application, that would involve editing a logback.xml at the root of the classpath.